# Openstack Horizon not working after a successful installation of Openstack using packstack

Tags: linux, centos7, openstack, dashboard, horizon

I'm facing a problem with OpenStack dashboard, I've install it on my centos7 server, the installation worked successfully but once i try to login via the dashboard i get : `The connection has timed out`

I have an access only from my command line.

Comment: Is there any logging available in /var/log/httpd?

Comment: Have you disabled the firewall on the Centos7 server? If not, do it. If yes, proceed to the usual network troubleshooting. First, check if anything is listening at port 80 `ss -lntp | grep ":80"`. Look at the logs as suggested by @BakaKuna. See if you can access the GUI from the Packstack server with `curl`.

Comment: i delete the first installation, i'm doing right now another one, i'm getting an error saying that : ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 10.53.193.172_controller.pp
Notice: /Stage[main]/Nova::Db::Sync/Exec[nova-db-sync]/returns: Error: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 'nova'@'10.53.193.172' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20210401-074033-eKhyZ8/manifests/10.53.193.172_controller.pp.log

Comment: It's not sufficient to delete the Packstack installation. Packstack has made many changes to your system that are not reverted by uninstalling the software, in particular it created a MariaDB database that you have probably not removed, and reconfigured your networking. For this reason, don't just re-run `packstack` after a failed run. **Always** reinstall the operating system first.

Comment: @berndbausch thank you for your advice ! i take it in consideration and reinstall the OS, but actually i don't know which configuration should i do to get the right OpenStack installation !